# Swift 2.0 convert issue NSFetchedResultsController didChangeObject

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

After convert in Swift 2.0 I can't resolve the issue:

> "Objective-C method
>   'controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:' 
>   provided by method
>   'controller(*:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:)'
>   conflicts with optional requirement method
>   'controller(*:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:)'
>   in protocol 'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'"

Please help me. 
And thanks advance

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: NSManagedObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    // the issue is here

    switch type {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        if let newIndex = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndex], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        if let index = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([index], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Signature is now `didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject`?

Comment: Mike Pollard - Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Change the call `didChangeObject anObject: NSManagedObject`  for `didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject`. The new method looks like this:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

}
```

[NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate/controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:)